# Configuring cmake version that ccmake uses

Tags: cmake, cmake-gui

I have a software that needs to use ***cmake 3.3 or higher***, so I built and installed ***cmake-3.4.1*** from source. I also installed the Cmake GUI (ccmake) from Ubuntu repositories, but when I execute it, it says that I have CMake Version 3.2.2. instead of 3.4.1. I would like to know how to configure it to use the version I installed. I have already exported *cmake 3.4.1* system variable in .baschrc (export PATH=$PATH:/home/.../.../cmake-3.4.1/bin) and nothing. I would appreciate any suggestion, thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The version of ccmake and cmake-gui are tight to the cmake version. In your build directory of your self-compiled CMake, there should be `ccmake` in the `bin` sub-directory. This what you want to use instead of the one installed from your Ubuntu package.

Comment: Ok, thanks, I removed all cmake versions installed from Ubuntu repositories, and now it's working, thanks

Comment: I would like to upvote, but I don't have enough reputation yet

Answer (score 0):

On ubuntu, browse to https://cmake.org/download/ and download the latest cmake installer for your platform (**cmake-3.5.1-Linux-x86_64.sh** for Ubuntu 64bit right now)

Open the terminal by pressing `Ctrl+Alt+T`

```
sudo apt-get remove cmake-qt-gui
sudo apt-get remove cmake
cd ~/Downloads 
sudo sh ./cmake-3.5.1-Linux-x86_64.sh --prefix=/usr
```

Accept the license (y)

Refuse to include subdirectory cmake (n)

You should now be able to execute the `cmake-gui` with a brand new 3.5.1 `cmake` using the command:

`cmake-gui`